# High RAM/MEMORY usage slows down website drastically (issue)!

Tags: magento-1.9, apache, memory, slow-response

We have a Magento 1.9 webshop with 10000 SKUs. Only 600 are in stock, and Magento is set not to show products that are out of stock. So only 600 products are displayed on the web site.

We have 20-30 attributes and 20-30 categories.

Hosting is VPS with 6GB of RAM, 4CPU and 250GB HDD. CentOS 6, Apache, MySQL

Generally, the web site was behaving OK, but lately (2-3 weeks) we started to face some issues with VERY slow load, or not load at all. We have noticed that this starts to happen when RAM total usage reach 60% or more. When RAM total usage is above 75%, the site can’t be load.

This happens 1-2-3 times per day, and when this happens we need to restart the server and then everything is working ok, until memory usage goes above 60%.

We are not able to find that triggers this issue?

```
Server health parameter "Services > Apache memory usage" changed its status from "yellow" to "red".

top - 04:05:43 up 1 day,  6:25,  0 users,  load average: 19.17, 19.58, 18.99
Tasks: 433 total,  17 running, 414 sleeping,   0 stopped,   2 zombie
Cpu(s): 47.2%us, 28.4%sy,  0.1%ni, 23.5%id,  0.3%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.3%st
Mem:   5990960k total,  5570892k used,   420068k free,   431168k buffers
Swap:  1048568k total,        0k used,  1048568k free,  2248852k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 1688 mysql     20   0 2169m  71m 4544 S 32.8  1.2   1760:23 mysqld
14065 servername   20   0  477m  70m  29m R 23.4  1.2   5:40.05 php-cgi
17509 servername   20   0  470m  59m  28m R 23.4  1.0   2:19.44 php-cgi
 9161 servername   20   0  492m  85m  29m R 21.8  1.5  11:51.10 php-cgi
14273 servername   20   0  479m  70m  28m R 21.8  1.2   5:35.93 php-cgi
19612 psaadm    20   0  335m  24m  15m R 21.8  0.4   0:00.18 sw-engine
 9942 servername   20   0  490m  83m  29m R 20.3  1.4  10:58.02 php-cgi
19303 servername   20   0  467m  57m  26m R 20.3  1.0   0:22.08 php-cgi
 8932 servername   20   0  490m  81m  27m R 18.7  1.4  12:09.62 php-cgi
 9626 servername   20   0  489m  78m  26m R 18.7  1.3  11:25.10 php-cgi
11242 servername   20   0  488m  79m  28m R 18.7  1.4   9:26.78 php-cgi
19430 servername   20   0  467m  56m  26m S 18.7  1.0   0:12.86 php-cgi
19577 servername   20   0  463m  43m  16m R 18.7  0.7   0:03.77 php-cgi
17307 servername   20   0  471m  61m  28m R 17.2  1.1   2:31.48 php-cgi
18962 servername   20   0  466m  56m  28m R 17.2  1.0   0:48.04 php-cgi
11035 servername   20   0  488m  79m  28m R 10.9  1.4   9:45.01 php-cgi
10481 servername   20   0  488m  81m  30m R  6.2  1.4  10:25.70 php-cgi
14191 servername   20   0  478m  71m  29m S  4.7  1.2   5:40.01 php-cgi
19602 root      30  10  171m  12m 5520 R  3.1  0.2   0:00.12 yum
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  1.6  0.0   0:04.70 ksoftirqd/0
 1944 apache    20   0  219m 7492  696 S  1.6  0.1   2:28.88 httpd
16742 apache    20   0  322m  13m 2692 S  1.6  0.2   0:00.19 httpd
19611 root      20   0 15292 1364  800 R  1.6  0.0   0:00.04 top
```

**--UPDATED-- 23.04.2020.**

We have noticed that this is the issue of bot attack. We have high connections access to Apache SSL/TLS, and bellow is some of logs:

```
2020-04-23 13:43:03 Access  114.119.162.226 200 GET /kategorija?lp_garancija=172&lp_hdd_filter_tip=48&lp_video_filter_tip=56&price=6%2C100_8%2C100_33%2C100_45%2C100_20%2C100 HTTP/1.0      Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0;) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; AspiegelBot) 57.9 K  Apache SSL/TLS access
2020-04-23 13:43:04 Access  114.119.163.210 200 GET /kategorija?lp_cpu_filter=16&lp_garancija=173_171&lp_hdd_filter_kapacitet=44_42&lp_video_filter_chipset=67&po_sales=1 HTTP/1.0      Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0;) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; AspiegelBot) 65.7 K  Apache SSL/TLS access
2020-04-23 13:43:04 Access  114.119.163.210 200 GET /kategorija?amp%3Blp_hdd_filter_kapacitet=46&lp_brand=69_74_71&lp_cpu_filter=17_16&lp_ekran_filter_rez=34&lp_garancija=172&price=1%2C1000 HTTP/1.0      Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0;) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; AspiegelBot) 67.9 K  Apache SSL/TLS access
2020-04-23 13:43:05 Access  114.119.165.215 200 GET /kategorija?lp_cpu_filter=20_15&lp_software_filter_os=63_91&price=4%2C1000 HTTP/1.0     Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0;) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; AspiegelBot) 69.7 K  Apache SSL/TLS access
2020-04-23 13:43:05 Access  114.119.164.55  200 GET /kategorija?lp_cpu_filter=16_15&lp_hdd_filter_tip=49&price=7%2C100_14%2C100_32%2C100_27%2C100_24%2C100 HTTP/1.0     Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0;) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; AspiegelBot) 69.8 K  Apache SSL/TLS access
2020-04-23 13:43:05 Access  54.36.148.191   302 GET /catalog/product_compare/add/product/4873/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubGFwdG9waS5iYS9rYXRlZ29yaWphP2xwX2NwdV9maWx0ZXI9MTcmYW1wO2xwX2dhcmFuY2lqYT0xNzM,/form_key/6FxeKHiMg78Kfj4b/ HTTP/1.0     Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/6.1; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)  862     Apache SSL/TLS access
2020-04-23 13:43:06 Access  114.119.162.226 200 GET /kategorija?lp_cpu_filter=22_24_94_93_15_201&lp_ekran_filter_rez=34&lp_hdd_filter_kapacitet=45&lp_ram_filter_kapacitet=39&lp_video_filter_tip=56 HTTP/1.0       Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0;) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; AspiegelBot) 44.2 K  Apache SSL/TLS access
2020-04-23 13:43:06 Access  46.229.168.142  200 GET /kategorija?price=6%2C100_15%2C100_9%2C100_24%2C100_19%2C100_12%2C100_40%2C100_13%2C100_21%2C100_37%2C100_28%2C100 HTTP/1.0     Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/6~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html) 152 K   Apache SSL/TLS access
2020-04-23 13:43:06 Access  114.119.162.164 200 GET /kategorija?lp_brand=76&lp_cpu_filter=21_13_16_15&price=9%2C100_23%2C100_30%2C100_35%2C100_26%2C100_24%2C100 HTTP/1.0       Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0;) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; AspiegelBot) 57.0 K  Apache SSL/TLS access
2020-04-23 13:43:07 Access  114.119.165.215 200 GET /kategorija?lp_hdd_filter_kapacitet=44&lp_hdd_filter_tip=48_49&lp_software_filter_os=63&price=6%2C100_53%2C100_34%2C100_41%2C100_45%2C100_15%2C100_54%2C100_27%2C100 HTTP/1.0       Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0;) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; AspiegelBot) 57.8 K  Apache SSL/TLS access
2020-04-23 13:43:07 Access  114.119.160.145 200 GET /kategorija?lp_cpu_filter=16_13_179&lp_hdd_filter_kapacitet=44_42&lp_hdd_filter_tip=48_51&lp_software_filter_os=63 HTTP/1.0     Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0;) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; AspiegelBot) 57.7 K  Apache SSL/TLS access
2020-04-23 13:43:08 Access  114.119.166.180 200 GET /kategorija?lp_hdd_filter_tip=49&price=7%2C100_36%2C100_24%2C100_38%2C100 HTTP/1.0      Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0;) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; AspiegelBot) 67.4 K  Apache SSL/TLS access
2020-04-23 13:43:08 Access  114.119.162.226 200 GET /kategorija?lp_cpu_filter=20_15&lp_garancija=172&lp_ram_filter_kapacitet=39_41&lp_software_filter_os=184_91_63&lp_video_filter_tip=56 HTTP/1.0
```

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: You may use this URL ( myip.ms) to determine how many sites are sharing your IP address.  Scroll down to second page for the count.  Share the count with us - we may suggest you find a 'dedicated' hosting plan.

Comment: Hi Wilson, thank you for your effort. I thinks we have been attacked by bots, mostly from Singapore. 

here are some more information.

2020-04-23 12:11:46 Access 54.36.148.168 302 GET /catalog/product_compare/add/product/6552/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubGFwdG9waS5iYS9rYXRlZ29yaWphP2xwX2JyYW5kPTcxJmFtcDtwcmljZT0yJTJDMTAwMA,,/form_key/38OwIulj65IG4NgE/ HTTP/1.0  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/6.1; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/) 814  Apache SSL/TLS access
2020-04-23 12:11:46 Access 114.119.166.132 200 GET /kategorija?lp_cpu_filter=20_179_16&lp_vi

Comment: The following URL may help you.  https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-block-foreign-ip-addresses

Comment: Consider using cloudflare.com services for hosting and protection.

Comment: @user15151 can you please post your answer so this question is closed out?

Comment: @brentwpeterson  On Apr 23, 2020 at 9:18 the link above to ahrefs.com/robot has the clues for minimizing robot activities by user.5151.